# Why execution time for reading a file in Chapel Language is different each time a file is read ? Can it be made same across several executions?

Tags: file, chapel

I am trying to analyse the performance of Chapel while doing serial I/O by reading a file with varying number of lines and measuring the time taken. I then plot this time on a graph. I find that each time the program is run, the time taken to read the file containing the same number of lines vary every time.
These are the graphs
[image]

[image]

This is the graph obtained across two executions. For each execution, I vary the number of lines in the file from 10 to 50000 in steps of 50.
The files that I have used

```
use Time;
config const quiet: bool = false;

var myfile=open("/home/sayanc/Cpp_programs/t2.txt",iomode.r);
var myreadingChannel=myfile.reader(locking=false);//reading channel with locking 
 disabled
var x:string;
var count:int=0;
//timer variable
var t:Timer;
t.start();
for line in myfile.lines()
{
  count=count+1;
}
t.stop();
// this is the file where the time is being stored.
var fout = open("/home/sayanc/Cpp_programs/chapel_locking_vs_nolocking_file_reading 
 time.txt", iomode.rw);

// Position a writing channel at the end of the file
var cout = fout.openAppender();

cout.writeln("Without Locking:",t.elapsed());

cout.close();
fout.close();

myreadingChannel.close();
myfile.close();
//reading the same file this time with locking enabled
myfile=open("/home/sayanc/Cpp_programs/t2.txt",iomode.r);
//locking enabled
myreadingChannel=myfile.reader();
count=0;
var t1:Timer;
t1.start();
for line in myfile.lines()
{
  count=count+1;

}


t1.stop();
//writeln(count);
fout = open("/home/sayanc/Cpp_programs/chapel_locking_vs_nolocking_file_reading 
time.txt", iomode.rw);

// Position a writing channel at the end of the file
cout = fout.openAppender();

cout.writeln("With locking:",t1.elapsed());

cout.close();
fout.close();

myreadingChannel.close();
myfile.close();

/* Create a writer channel with a starting offset at the end of the file */
proc file.openAppender() {
var writer = this.writer(start=this.size);
return writer;
```

This is the chapel code for reading the file.The graph shown above is obtained using locking=false option.

I use a C++ program to write the lines in the file.

So, I would like to know why is it that reading the same number of lines takes different times across different executions?
}

Comment: It seems there is an implicit assumption in this question that the variation is specific to the Chapel language; have you tested an equivalent program with e.g. C/C++ to confirm whether the read time is predictable with other languages?

Comment: @JoshMilthorpe Ya I have tested with C++ the same code. Ya there is variation but not at at such extremes. The variations have been very minor.